# Vuetify 3 unable to set a dynamic value for VSelect component

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I wrote the following Vue 3 code that uses Vuetify 3 to render a data table with a select component on top of each column to map each column to a specific field:

```
<script setup>
const headers = [
      {
        title: 'Column A',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: false,
        key: 'col_a',
      },
      {
        title: 'Column B',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: false,
        key: 'col_b',
      }];

const items = [
      {
        col_a: 'John',
        col_b: 'Doe',
      },
      {
        col_a: 'Foo',
        col_b: 'Bar',
      }];
const selectItems = ref([
  { value: "firstName", label: "Name" },
  { value: "lastName", label: "Surname" },
]);

const handleSelectChanges = (v) => {
  console.log(v);
};
</script>
<template>
...
    <v-data-table
        class="elevation-1"
        no-data-text="No items found"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :hide-default-footer="true"
    >
        <template v-slot:headers="{ columns }">
        <tr>
            <template v-for="column in columns" :key="column.key">
            <td>
                <v-select
                item-title="label"
                item-value="value"
                label="Please select"
                :items="selectItems"
                @update:modelValue="handleSelectChanges"
                >
                <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
                    <v-list-item
                    v-bind="props"
                    :value="`${column.key}|${item.value}`"
                    :subtitle="`${column.key}|${item.value}`"
                    ></v-list-item>
                </template>
                </v-select>
            </td>
            </template>
        </tr>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
...
</template>
```

I'm expecting to receive in *handleSelectChanges* something like *col_a|firstName* but unfortunately I only get *firstName*. I don't understand with the value is not modified dynamically. It's weird since the *Subtitle* is correctly set.

Any andice on how to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

VSelect will return the value resolved from looking up the property in the `item-value` prop on the selected item. So in your case, you will get the `value` prop, which is `firstName` or `lastName`.

Use the [`return-object`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-return-object) prop to have VSelect return the whole item object.

Though from what you describe, it might be easier to just bind VSelect to the `column.value` property directly (see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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))